# How do i make giant entities?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I make giant mobs in Minecraft? I know how to summon giants and giant withers but no other giant mobs. I would like to know how to summon giant ender dragons. Any nbt tags are appreciated, as well.

Comment: You can't make a giant version of most mobs. The only other possible one is a giant slime.

Comment: I knew that you could also use the size nbt tag for slimes and lavaslimes

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to make giant mobs currently, except for Slimes and Magma Cubes.

The Giant, although it uses the same skin as a Zombie, is a different entity, and it's appearance isn't related to any NBT tags.

Same goes for the Wither, who doesn't use the same ID as Wither Skeletons.

For Slimes and Magma Cubes, you can set the Size tag to any value from 0 (smallest natural Slime) to 255.

Comment: to summon giant wither type this in /summon Witherboss ~ ~ ~ {Invul:10000}

Comment: @MyTreeko The Invul tag for the Wither is specific to that entity. The Giant is a separate entity, and is in no way related to zombies (except for the texture). Slimes and Magma Cubes have the specific `Size` tag used only with them. All in all, "giant mobs" are just other features implemented for reasons other than to have giant mobs, but can be used for that purpose